# ¿ Como hacer mi script de cookies con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Estoy tratando de hacer el script de las cookies de mi pagina con JQuery, ya que se supone que debe ser mas dinámico.
Mi experiencia es corta en JavaScript y leyendo y viendo ejemplos, solo conseguí lo que les muestro continuación, que funciona pero resulta poco dinámico.
Si pueden ayudarme a hacer un script con JQuery les agradecería, o bien decirme donde encontrar información al respecto.
Quiero tratar de hacer mi script en JQuery si es posible de alguna manera.
Gracias.

***EDITO LA PREGUNTA:***

> Necesito conseguir hacer la lógica de mi código en JQuery ya que mi
>   experiencia y conocimiento son nulos y conseguir un código dinámico y efectivo.

```js
function getCookie(c_name){
 var c_value = document.cookie;
 var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
 if (c_start == -1){
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
 }
 if (c_start == -1){
  c_value = null;
 }else{
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1){
   c_end = c_value.length;
  }
  c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
 }
 return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
 var exdate=new Date();
 exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
 var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
 document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

if(getCookie('tiendaaviso')!="1"){
 document.getElementById("aceptacion").style.display="block";
}
function PonerCookie(){
 setCookie('tiendaaviso','1',365);
 document.getElementById("aceptacion").style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Mis cookies</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="aceptacion">
    <div class="inner">
  
  Esta sitio web utiliza cookies con fines estadisticos  
  <a href="#" title="cookies" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer noopener" class="info">Más información</a>
      
      
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ok" onclick="PonerCookie();"><b>OK</b></a> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="coookiesJQuery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con más dinámico y efectivo? ¿Cuál es el problema que tiene el código que compartes?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro He leído en varios sitios que con jQuery las cookies son mas dinámicas y fluidas, por decirlo de algún modo. Que seria mas rápido todo con JQuery, por eso quiero adaptar mi código a esta librería de que he leído, pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: No sé a qué se referirán con más dinámicas y fluidas, pero ten en cuenta que jQuery es una biblioteca hecha en JavaScript para simplificar algunas tareas. Por tanto, el código en jQuery podrá ser más limpio y sencillo que la misma tarea hecha en JavaScript puro, pero va a ser menos eficiente y menos rápido. A lo que me refiero es que, si el código que tienes en JavaScript puro te funciona, puedes cambiarlo a jQuery para practicar o  dejarlo más "limpio/legible", pero eso no lo va a hacer más eficiente o mejor.

Comment: Dicho eso, esta es una pregunta interesante. ¿Has probado a usar algún plugin de cookies para jQuery?¿Con qué problemas te estás encontrando al hacer la conversión?

Comment: No he probado el plugin de jQuery, de echo no sabría como hacerlo. Creo entender lo que quieres decirme. ¿ Hay forma de optimizar mas mi código sin usar jQuery? ¿ Donde encuentro información sobre el plugin de jQuery? Gracias @AlvaroMontoro